# How to add a module in Yootheme Pro

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates

It's been a few months and after a lot of searching and reading, I still don't know how to use Yootheme Pro in Joomla.

I did try to find a developer and pay just to get the template working on a basic level, but nobody seems to work with Joomla anymore so I'm stuck here and getting crazy, because I need to update the site and I get no support from Yootheme.

Does anyone know how to add a Joomla page using builder?

I need to enter a module with the latest articles in the home page. See the page [here](https://www.portal-gestao.com/home-baixo-2.html)

This is how builder looks like:
[image]

I tried creating the module within builder from scratch and using an existing module but nothing works.

Can anyone help?

I'm using Joomla 3.8.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This module is not working with Yootheme you can use alternatives like

Latest News Enhanced (free + pro)
or 
Tag Similar (free)

Both free versions can do much more than the default Recent Artikel Modul and they work with yootheme

- Assign the Modul to ALL MENUS
- Make it Public - even for testing
- Select the Public Recent NEWS Enhanced Modul in YOO Builder
- Place J!Modul where ever you need it

Hope it helps, had the exact same problem with YOO and this modul